# I can't install Laravel 6, it shows me this error

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to install Laravel 6 with composer but show me this error.

```
C:\Users\jofre>cd C:\xampp\htdocs

C:\xampp\htdocs>laravel new blog --auth Crafting application...

In CurlFactory.php line 200:

  cURL error 28: Failed to connect to 190.195.101.53 port 1080: Timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl   -errors.html)


new [--dev] [--auth] [-f|--force] [--] [<name>]
```

I tried another way to solve this. I successfully installed Laravel with command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "6.*"` but now I can't run `composer require laravel/ui`. It shows me this error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\blog>composer require laravel/ui
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/ui
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].


    - laravel/ui v2.0.0 requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - laravel/ui v2.0.1 requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - laravel/ui v2.0.2 requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
```

and

```
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.8.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.9.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.9.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.11, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.11].
    - Installation request for laravel/ui ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[2.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Version info:

`LARAVEL VERSION: const VERSION = '6.18.11';`

Comment: hello,  I can´t. When I install with 'composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "6.*" ' no have trouble, but when I try put 'composer require laravel/ui' show a error that I put in the answer.

Comment: ok sorry. I dont have another internet connection

Comment: yes, I did it. I can to edit the answer to show you the error

Comment: I just installed the same version of Laravel as you (`php composer.phar global require laravel/framework:6.18.11`). I then added the installer (`php composer.phar global require laravel/installer`). I then ran the app generator (`/root/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel new blog --auth`) and it was fine. I used a completely clean PHP environment.

Comment: Your message `Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.11 ..)` makes me wonder - I think you have a non-global `composer.json` in the second attempt (`composer require laravel/ui`) that you are not showing. Here is [the build output](https://justpaste.it/41vyo).

Comment: I can't explain your networking error though. Are you somewhere where your internet might be being filtered? Try using a VPN to see if that fixes it.

Comment: To build a completely new environment I used Docker with a clean base image. You don't have to use Docker, but it is very good for making sure there is nothing in the environment that is interfering with your commands.

Comment: ok dear, First I going to change my internet name and pass connection.

Answer (score 1):

i use

composre create-project laravel/laravel blog "6.*"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).